# File output error

Tags: c++

My program crashes after the user inputs outputFileName.
`c1` is a char array, `out` is a string and `len` is an int with the length of c1.

Here is my code:

```
    ofstream outFile;
    char outputFileName[256];
    cout << "Enter output file name: ";
    cin >> outputFileName;
    cout << endl;
    outFile.open(outputFileName,ios::trunc);
    for(int i=0; i<len-1; i++){ //-1 b/c added \n at the end.
        out[i] = c1[i];
    }
    outFile << out;
    outFile.close();
```

Comment: Is `out` a `string` that already has `out.size() >= len`? If not, you can't assign to it that way.

Comment: How does the program crash? Does it crash before or after opening the file? Why are you copying the content of a char array to a string? Why are you copying one char at a time? And if len is really the length, why are you copying all chars but one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd do something more like this:

```
{    
    std::cout << "Please enter output file name: ";

    std::string outputFileName;       
    std::getline(outputFileName, std::cin);

    std::ofstream outputFile(outputFileName.c_str());
    outputFile.write((static_cast<char *>(&c1), len);
} // file closes automatically when it goes out of scope.
```

Comment: I fixed it getting rid of out and adding c1 directly to the file.

    ofstream outFile;
    char outputFileName[256];
    cout << "Enter output file name: ";
    cin >> outputFileName;
    cout << endl;
    outFile.open(outputFileName,ios::trunc);
    for(int i=0; i<len-1; i++){ //-1 b/c added \n at the end.
        outFile  = c1[i];
    }
    outFile.close();

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it getting rid of out and writing c1 directly to the file.

```
ofstream outFile;
char outputFileName[256];
cout << "Enter output file name: ";
cin >> outputFileName;
cout << endl; outFile.open(outputFileName,ios::trunc);
for(int i=0; i<len-1; i++){ //-1 b/c added \n at the end. 
    outFile = c1[i];
} 
outFile.close();
```